# wpf combobox selected item

Tags: wpf, combobox, selecteditem

I have a wpf app with a combobox like this

```
<ComboBox name="cmbBx1">
  <ComboBoxItem Name=Jan">January</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem Name=Feb">February</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

In the code behind I need to get the value of the item that was selected to pass to a stored procedure.  I can get part of the way by doing this:

```
ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)cmbBx1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(cmbBx1.SelectedItem);
```

The problem is that the output of that gives me something like System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: January

I just need the value, i.e. "January" returned.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the contents of the ComboBoxItem.

```
string month = cbi.Content.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

cmbBx1.SelectedItem directly. It will give you the currently Selected Item.

Answer (score 0):

To get the text/value only you need to do

cbi.Content.ToString() after that line...